# Groovy JsonSlurper to fetch JSON data from URL. Error : The API package 'urlfetch' or call 'Fetch()' was not found

Tags: json, google-app-engine, groovy, bitbucket

My groovy script connects to the bitbucket API and fetches the branch details. This is the script:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText( new URL( 'https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/repositories/repo_name/repo_name.git/branches/' ).text )
```

But this throwing the following error:

```
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: The API package 'urlfetch' or call 'Fetch()' was not found.
at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:2)
```

But when I copy paste the URL on browser I am able to see the JSON data. How to fetch the JSON data from this URL using groovy?

Comment: What about authentication?

Comment: Its showing me the JSON data without asking for authorization in browser. So is it required to pass it here?

Comment: This is a Google app engine restriction. Mentioning gae in your question would have been helpful

Comment: I guess it is, otherwise I'll be allowed to view all bitbucket's repos.

Comment: @Opal. I passed username and password as authorization header. I am able to fetch the data now. Thanks.

Comment: @shwetha, great! May I add my suggestion as an answer to be accepted?

Comment: shwetha, Can you provide an example of passing the username/password as part of the auth header? I'm assuming it was using the requestProperties parameter, but I'm not sure of the exact syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works from browser since you're already authenticated. If you want it to work from command line/script you need to add authentication part as well.

Answer (score 1):

Code for authentication

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
String apiurl1 = "https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/repositories/repo_name/repo_name.git/branches/"
String apiurl2 = "https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/repositories/repo_name2/repo_name2.git/branches/"
String username = "username" 
String password = "password"
String userpass = username + ":" + password; 
String basicAuth = "Basic " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass.getBytes());

URL url = apiurl1.toURL();
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization",basicAuth);
InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
def names = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(inputStream.text);
connection.disconnect();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText( new URL( 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users' ).text )

json.each { println it }
```

I was able to use this code to parse JSON URL data.